# Import from XML with same tags

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have XML file and I need to parse it and import data to database. I using `XDocument` to parse file, but there is question:

Sample of XML:

```
<a b="1">dfas</a>
<a b="2">qwsd</a>
<a b="3">egfs</a>
<a b="4">ghfg</a>
```

My code:

```
 XElement tag;
 record.A = tag.Element("a").Value;
```

I need to import to record.  A value of element with attribute b=4. How can I do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
record.A = tag.Elements("a").First(a => a.Attribute("b").Value == "4").Value;
```

or

```
record.A = (string)tag.Elements("a").FirstOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("b").Value == "4");
```

or

```
record.A = (string)tag.XPathSelectElement("//a[@b='4']");
```